# Xcode11 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code with SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, sdwebimage, xcode11

Recently I migrated to Xcode11.1 after that when I try to run the code in Xcode 11.1.  It started showing  me the following error:

> “/Debug-iphonesimulator/DigitalCollection.app/Frameworks/SDWebImage.framework/SDWebImage:
>   No such file or directory
>
> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code”

**Pod file configuration  pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'**

I removed derived data, clean the project and even restarted the Xcode but no luck.

Any help can be appreciated.

Comment: make sure you have run pod install and also that you are opening the workspace, not the project

Comment: @Scriptable yes i run the pod install and opening the project through workspace

Answer (score 1):

You have your **SDWebImage** pinned to version 4 for starters.

Taking a glance at the release notes, I spot this on their first 5.x release:

> 5.0 Patch - Xcode 11 Compatible

I would suggest updating to their most recent version if possible (5.2.3).

https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/releases